# Fetch search engine of other website on your website

Tags: php

How do i fetch search engine of other website and also result of that website on my own using HTMLdom API. Answer will be appreciated

Comment: This is the website of which i want to fetch search engine: http://banggood.com

Comment: This question is to broad with not enough input, look into `curl`  http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: First you must conspire to violate the site's terms of service, then you have to steal content.

Comment: Not it will be done with the consent of both parties

Answer (score 0):

combining two techniques you can achieve your goal.

1. CURL
2. Simple PHP Dom parser

   // php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

   // simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Comment: If you need to display the search result you need only simple html dom. For your convenience I'm adding another answer.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Form.html

```
 <form method="get" action="url_look.php">
 <input type="text" name="keywords"/>
 <input type="submit"  value="submit"/>
 </form>
```

### 2. url_look.php

```
require_once('uploads/simple_html_dom.php');
$keywords = str_replace(" ","-",$_GET['keywords']);
$url =  "http://www.banggood.com/search/$keywords.html";
$html = file_get_html($url);
echo "<ul>";
foreach($html->find('span[class=title]') as $product_title){
//for more details visit http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.html
echo "<li>".$product_title."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Great! it worked! How can we show images and price as well in grid divs

Comment: I think they are using a lazy loading technology for fetching images after the dom has been loaded. So we cannot get the images in the html document that we fetched. We need to find another solution for this. I'll update if I find one

Comment: Can i have your email?

Comment: aqueelvp@gmail.com

Comment: this is not my personal mail id, even though i will reply